# Helper class to interact with Unity's PlayerPrefs system

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity3D has a class for platform-independent data storage called `PlayerPrefs`. Supported data types: `int`, `float` and `string` can be retrieved and set using static methods, but no `bool` support exists, and you have to manually call `Save()` to make sure value changes persist.

I wrote a little helper class to cut down on the the boilerplate, and also add support for `bool` and `enum` datatypes. I'm looking for a general critique on style and efficiency, there's a fair amount of duplication, but I'm not sure how I can reduce that.

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper class that simplifies common PlayerPrefs getting and setting.
/// </summary>
public static class PlayerPrefsHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an int value from PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method has a side effect of creating a PlayerPrefs entry for the given key if one does not exist.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value.</param>
    /// <returns>The int value stored in PlayerPrefs for the given key, or defaultValue if no such key exists</returns>
    public static int GetInt(string key, int defaultValue)
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
        {
            SetInt(key, defaultValue);
        }

        return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an int value on PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetInt(string key, int value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a bool value from PlayerPrefs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method has a side effect of creating a PlayerPrefs entry for the given key if one does not exist.
    /// The value will be converted from an integer value, because PlayerPrefs does not support boolean values. 0 will be converted to false, all other values will be converted to true.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value.</param>
    /// <returns>The bool value stored in PlayerPrefs for the given key, or defaultValue if no such key exists</returns>
    public static bool GetBool(string key, bool defaultValue)
    {
        return GetInt(key, defaultValue ? 1 : 0) != 0;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a bool value on PlayerPrefs.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The value will be stored as an integer, because PlayerPrefs does not support boolean values. True will be stored as 1, false as 0.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetBool(string key, bool value)
    {
        SetInt(key, value ? 1 : 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a float value from PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method has a side effect of creating a PlayerPrefs entry for the given key if one does not exist.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value.</param>
    /// <returns>The float value stored in PlayerPrefs for the given key, or defaultValue if no such key exists</returns>
    public static float GetFloat(string key, float defaultValue)
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
        {
            SetFloat(key, defaultValue);
        }

        return PlayerPrefs.GetFloat(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a float value on PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetFloat(string key, float value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat(key, value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a string value from PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method has a side effect of creating a PlayerPrefs entry for the given key if one does not exist.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value.</param>
    /// <returns>The string value stored in PlayerPrefs for the given key, or defaultValue if no such key exists</returns>
    public static string GetString(string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(key))
        {
            SetString(key, defaultValue);
        }

        return PlayerPrefs.GetString(key);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets a string value on PlayerPrefs
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public static void SetString(string key, string value)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(key, value);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value from PlayerPrefs as enumerated type T.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method has a side effect of creating a PlayerPrefs entry for the given key if one does not exist.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of enum expected.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="defaultValue">The default value if no PlayerPrefs setting exists for the key.</param>
    /// <returns>The value stored in PlayerPrefs for the given key, converted to type T, or defaultValue if no such key exists</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">T must be an enumerated type</exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Cannot get an enum that doesn't have underlying type Int32.</exception>
    public static T GetEnum<T>(string key, T defaultValue) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var enumType = typeof(T);

        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }

        if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(int))
        {
            var value = GetInt(key, defaultValue.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return (T)Enum.ToObject(enumType, value);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot get an enum that doesn't have underlying type Int32.");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets an int value on PlayerPrefs based on an enumerated value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of enum.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">T must be an enumerated type</exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">Cannot store an enum that doesn't have underlying type Int32.</exception>
    public static void SetEnum<T>(string key, T value) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var enumType = typeof(T);

        if (!enumType.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }

        if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) == typeof(int))
        {
            SetInt(key, value.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot store an enum that doesn't have underlying type Int32.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Get*() methods

Checking if preference is exist and creating it is not necessary. You can get the same (from game's perspective) behavior by shorter code:

```
public static int GetInt(string key, int defaultValue)
{
    return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Entries won't be created on getting anymore, obviously, but you probably don't need such behavior at all, since you'll likely interact with Preferences only through PlayerPrefs and PlayerPrefsHelper classes.

## Duplication

Since you want to reduce duplication, here are two ways I see to do it:

### *Enum() duplication

Why not extract same code to separate method?

```
public static void SetEnum<T>(string key, T value) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    CheckEnum<T>();
    SetInt(key, value.ToInt32(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}

private static void CheckEnum<T>()
{
    var enumType = typeof(T);

    if (!enumType.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    }

    if (Enum.GetUnderlyingType(enumType) != typeof(int))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot store an enum that doesn't have underlying type Int32.");
    }
}
```

### Save() duplication

```
public static void SetInt(string key, int value)
{
    DoAndSave(() => PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key, value));
}

private static void DoAndSave(Action action)
{
    action();
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

[I'm not sure if it's worth it though.](http://ericlippert.com/2015/04/23/dry-out-your-policies/)

Comment: Thanks for the advice! As for the creating a key if it doesn't exist bit, that was actually my main motivation for creating this helper class, since that way I can define defaults at the start and not have to program in hard defaults in every script that access a particular key.

Comment: But all your methods require a default value as the second parameter, don't they?

Comment: Ah good point, I don't think I've thought this design all the way through...